# Characters Disallowed in CodeIgniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, uri

```
var url =  "<?php echo site_url('/main/getSearchResults'); ?>";    
$.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: searchString,
            success: function(result){
                var restaurant_array =   JSON.parse(result);
                var result_list='';
                for(var i=0;i<restaurant_array.length;i++){
                    result_list = '<li data-icon="false"><a href="#">'+restaurant_array[i].name+'</a></li>'+result_list;
                }
                $('#search-basic').html(result_list);
                $('#search-basic').listview('refresh');
            }           
        });
```

I am using codeigniter. In my js file I have written the above code. Its showing "Disallowed characters" during ajax call. I guess URI is having some unaccepted characters. Is there any solution for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does `searchString` contain when you are testing?

Comment: Its just regular characters from a text box. When I give the exact URL instead of using <?php..?> in the AJAX, it works.

Comment: Can you echo out that php outside of the javascript?

Comment: You mean <?php echo site_url('/main/getSearchResults'); ?> ?

Comment: Yeah. does that work in general on the page?

Comment: Yes, Its working on other pages. I think in code-igniter by default some characters are not allowed in URL. Is it the reason ?

Comment: on other pages? Is this in a `.js` file?

Comment: Also, Codeigniter is just a framework, it doesn't have any impact of things like this. It's just using PHP.

Comment: Yes, This code is in a JS file.

Comment: Well there you go! I'll add an answer.

Comment: I've added it. You can see below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to save it as `.php` file in order to use PHP as it is a server-side language. You cannot execute PHP from a `.js` file.